# Text is stretched - sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I have a `SKLabelNode` called round. Here is the code for that below:

```
round = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "arial")
round.text = "Round: 1"
round.color = UIColor.white
round.fontSize = 20
round.position.x = 150
round.position.y = 100
round.zPosition = 5
self.addChild(round)
```

For some reason, the text appears to display very wierd. Here is a screenshot.
[image: stretched image]

Also, I think it is important to mension, I have included this line:

`scene?.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.resizeFill`

How can I make the text normal again?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Try aspectFill or aspectFit instead of resizeFill. I think aspect fit will work for you.

Comment: It fixed the problem, but it also made new problems for me, so I cannot use aspect fit.

Comment: If you use resizeFill, this will happen on certain screens based on what your original scene size on.  There is no other workaround for it except for changing the scaleMode to something that won't stretch the scene.

Comment: resizeFill should not cause any stretching or scaling, you are thinking of .fill

Comment: If your text is stretched like the picture about, and you are using a scale mode of `resizeFill`, then you have a problem with how your `SKView` is set to scale.  Either that, or you are not giving us a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to replicate your problem, so I am going to have to assume you are not correctly using scaleMode, and it is defaulting to `.fill`